# How do I turn on zone-while-idle in emacs through my .emacs?

Tags: emacs

Rather than `M-x zone-when-idle <RET> 30` i'd like this to be the default. What can I add to my .emacs to achieve this? I tried:

```
(zone-when-idle 30)
```

and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(require 'zone)
(zone-when-idle 30)
```

works on Emacs 24. If you have a look at the `zone-when-idle` code, it does nothing else but enabling a timer.

Comment: Is there anyway to choose which *type of zone* to run?